# Why compiler treats closures and local functions differently?

Tags: function, swift, closures

I thought closures and functions are same thing. But when referencing to a property inside local function compiler doesn't require self. But inside closure it requires to write self. What i mean is why this two things are different?

The sample code for clarity:

```
class Foo {
    let bar = "bar"

    func baz() {
        func localBaz() {
            println(bar)   // No complain from compiler.
        }

        let bazClosure = {
            println(self.bar) // Here if I write just println(bar), compiler complains.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You expectation is wrong - functions and closures in Swift are not the same thing.  A `func` essentially sets up a `lazy var` binding with a `[unowned self]` declaration.  Thus, if you want to get rid of `func` you could transform the following:

```
class Foo {
  let bar = "bar"
  // this is not your 'baz'; just an example
  func baz () { println (bar) }
  }
}
```

as

```
class Foo {
  let bar = "bar"
  lazy var baz = { [unowned self] in println (self.bar) }
}
```

You can see that `func` is doing more than just a closure.

Furthermore, and importantly, `func` sets up a recursive binding environment which allows the body of `func bar` to reference `bar`.  Thus you can write:

```
  1> class Foo { 
  2.     func fact (x:Int) -> Int {
  3.         if 1 == x { return x } 
  4.         else { return x * fact (x - 1) }} 
  5. }    
  6> Foo().fact(5)
$R0: (Int) = 120
```

but not

```
  7> class Foo { 
  8.     lazy var fact = { (x:Int) -> Int in 
  9.         if 1 == x { return x } 
 10.         else { return x * fact (x - 1) }}} 
repl.swift:10:27: error: variable used within its own initial value
        else { return x * fact (x - 1) }}}

                      ^
```

Comment: You are right they are not the same thing. In Apple's swift book it says “Global and nested functions, as introduced in Functions, are actually special cases of closures.”. But Until now I didn't know what this spacial case is. Thank you for useful info

Comment: To be fair, I think this goes to show that they *are* the same thing, and that func is just shorthand for binding the closure expression to a name, with how that works explaining the behavior with `self`.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, I do not know why `closure` need self in swift to access instance properties but let's think about it.

Your `baz()` is a class function, I mean it belongs to the class `Foo` and the `closure` like a external function. In Objective-C all class function actually need a `self` argument to invoke that function.

Therefore a `closure` need a `self` pointer (or something named `self` reference the instance of `Foo`) to access its property.